# icon image not working on IE / FireFox / Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have an icon image that will not show up on IE / Chrome / Firefox, seems to only be working with `Comodo Dragon` Browser, can anyone help me figure out why. Please And Thanks.  :) ......   so i figure out .png works with all browsers but .gif does not.. is there any reason why ?

css

```
#imagetest {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:50px;
  height:50%;
  z-index:9998;
  left:-10px;
}

#imagetest {
  top:90%;
  z-index:9999;
}

#imagetest img {
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;
  left:45px;
  width:120px;
}
```

html

```
<div id="imagetest"><a href="linktarget" target="_blank"><img 
src="http://i.imgur.com/justatestlinkreallinkworksfine.gif" border="0" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think image source is invalid.

Comment: You need to change `http:imagelink,gif` to `http://image.gif` with two slashes [//] after the colon [:]

Comment: And the closing of the `<a>` tag in your html?

Comment: yes i have closing tag of a also , sry i deleted some of the real code and forgot to add the closing <a> tag

Comment: Image source appears broken since we can't open it.

Comment: There are two **#imagetest** IDs, one with top:0 and another one is top:90%, but why..?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz  the link is irrelevant to the question, the image works fine.. that's not the real link obviously.  would be a good reason why it doesn't work tho haha.. thanks tho

Comment: @WebDevRon  that's irrelevant to the question also.. does not fix why the image does not show on anything but comodo dragon.. i took off the 90% anyway.. i don't know why i had that in both spots lol

Comment: @V_JOSH_C Try to set the height of the image.... it will work.

Comment: @V_JOSH_C Can you paste the link of jsfiddle for more clearity of the code?

Comment: @JafferWilson   does not help

Comment: @JafferWilson    [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekgq67sm/1/)  
icon works in JSFiddle.. but will not work on IE / Chrome / Firefox   the icon is the Whatsapp

Comment: @V_JOSH_C Not understood which image is not getting displayed? Please clarify

Comment: the icon that is not working is the whatsapp ,   its the green phone